# How to migrate the website hosting from siteground to google cloud?

Tags: web, web-hosting, google-cloud-platform, cloud-hosting

Currently my website is hosted with site ground and i want to host it with google cloud. I have made an account with google cloud but i do not know how to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use rsync via SSH to migrate everything you have from SiteGround to Google Cloud.

Use this sintax: rsync [flags] [local path] [user]@[remote server]:[remote path]

For example: transfering files from local machine to another one:

rsync -avzhe ssh /home/backup.tar.gz root@xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:/backups/

Of course you need to have root and SSH access into your Google Cloud instance.

If you have a control panel on your Siteground server the procedure is different, mainly because for example WHM/cPanel has an automated way of transferring accounts from one WHM instance to another.

My advice is to ask Siteground for help or advice for this migration of yours. One month ago, my [host](http://rosehosting.com) migrated three website of mine with every corresponding config file and database for less than 2 hours, while I was drinking coffee with my lovely wife.
Ask your web host for help, maybe they will migrate everything for you.

I hope that my answer will help you.